# Define std::string in C++ without escape characters

Tags: c++, string, escaping

What would be the most painless way to input un-escaped characters sequence to `std::string`?

Instead of

```
 std::string st = "C:\\program files\\myFile.txt";
```

something like: (Doesn't work correctly due to escape characters).

```
 std::string st = "C:\program files\myFile.txt";
```

Comment: How are you building?  Can you store the content in a `.txt` file and add a `Makefile` rule to convert it to a .`h` file?

Comment: @MikeSamuel, I am using Visual Studio.

Comment: Can the downvoter explain what is wrong in the question?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For filenames, just use (forward? back?) the other direction slash.  It works on Windows too:

```
std::string st = "C:/program files/myFile.txt";
```

Comment: @chris: Thanks, but your effort is wasted. I'll just forget again because my brain doesn't consider it important enough to remember.

Comment: This won't always work with some file system drivers, or if the path is longer than MAX_PATH and the extended path prefix is used

Comment: @Asu: Why would you say that?

Comment: Sorry, I mixed it up. I've mixed up `/` with `\\`.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not what OP asked.

Comment: @TommyD: I'm on Stack Overflow to solve problems, not answer questions. Questions often come with incorrect assumptions about what is possible.

Answer (score 87):

You can do it with C++11 [raw string literals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#New_string_literals):

```
std::string st = R"(C:\program files\myFile.txt)";
```

Comment: Awesome.  LR for wide character.  And the syntax confused me at first because the delimiters for the beginning and end of the string are double character sequences... "( ...and then... )"

Comment: Ew this syntax is disgusting. Whose bright idea was it to put the () in quotes? And the alternative version, R"delimiter()delimiter", is even worse.