# How to disable the escape sequence in C++

Tags: c++, path, escaping

I use C++ to process many files, and I have to write the file name in source code like this:
`"F:\\somepath\\subpath\\myfile"`,
I wonder that if there's any way to get rid of typing "\\" to get a character '\' in string literal context, i.e, I hope I can just write `"F:\somepath\subpath\myfile"` instead the boring one.

Comment: could you please give me an example?

Comment: ...and do not hardcode any path too...

Comment: Technically it's wrong, because a forward slash will create a forward slash in the string, not a backslash. But in case of filesystem paths you can mix \ and / as you like. At least on Windows.

Comment: @Јοеу Of course the forward slash will create a forward slash in the file name.  But the forward slash is a valid directory seporator.

Comment: Store your paths in external config files, or pass them via arguments. Don't keep it in the code, it's the troublestarter

Comment: possible duplicate of [Define std::string in C++ without escape characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10501599/define-stdstring-in-c-without-escape-characters)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Solutions:

1. use C++11 string literals: `R"(F:\somepath\subpath\myfile)"`
2. Use boost::path with forward slashes:
   They will validate your path and raise exceptions for problems.

   ```
   boost::filesystem::path p = "f:/somepath/subpath";
   p /= "myfile";
   ```
3. just use forward slashes; Windows should understand them.

Answer (score 5):

Two obvious options:

1. Windows understands forward slashes (or rather, it translates them to backslashes);  use those instead.
2. C++11 has raw string literals.  Stuff inside them doesn't need to be escaped.

   ```
   R"(F:\somepath\subpath\myfile)"
   ```

Answer (score 4):

Since C++11, you can use raw string literals (see [string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) for more details):

```
std::string s = R"(F:\somepath\subpath\myfile)";
```

On the other hand, you can just use forward slashes for filesystem paths:

```
std::string s = "F:/somepath/subpath/myfile";
```

Comment: I think parentheses are required for raw string literals, such as `R"(F:\somepath\subpath\myfile)"`, at least with gcc and MSVC.