# Is there something equivelant in c++(or c++11) for @ like in c#?

Tags: c++

In C# we can define a complicated string with @:

```
string str = @"This is the first line.\r\nThis is still the first line";
```

how about in C++? if we have something like this we don't need to use converting sign '\' for all the special characters.

Comment: Yes, raw string literals. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10501599/define-stdstring-in-c-without-escape-characters/10501649#10501649

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++11 (only) you can use a raw string literal:

```
std::string str = R"(This is the first line.\r\nThis is still the first line)";
```

Comment: You're missing parentheses.